# How do you add roles rolify using cancan and devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, rolify

I get that there are a lot of questions on this subject but none have really answered what i'm looking for.

I'm attempting to use rolify to define my roles in cancan, i was able to make an admin role via rails console and set the default role for new users.

My question is how do i set a batch of roles to different values and assign those roles to certain users?

If you have a good tutorial that explains this process that would help as well, screencasts preferred.

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How do you create a batch of roles?

You can do this in your db/seeds.rb file, which is executed each time you run rake db:seed

```
[:admin, :author, :contact, :user].each do |role|
  Role.find_or_create_by_name({ name: role }, without_protection: true)
end
```

Adding a role to someone is done like

```
@user.add_role :admin
```

You check whether a user has a certain role using

```
@user.has_role? :admin
```

And, as Steve already said, the https://github.com/EppO/rolify documentation should get you on the move!

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your question is more complicated than this, but the simple answer is that you use `add_role`. You don't have to do anything to create the roles other than assign them to something. So if Jane is globally an admin and Joe is a peon, you could just use:

```
User.where(name: 'Joe').add_role :peon
User.where(name: 'Jane').add_role :admin
```

You can also add roles with respect to specific classes or instances of classes, but the above was the most direct answer to your question. The [README](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) on github is pretty decent as tutorials go.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that the method used in Danny's answer doesn't work for me in Rails 4

What I found to work is putting this into your seeds.rb file

```
[:admin, :author, :contact, :user].each do |role|
  Role.where({ name: role }, without_protection: true).first_or_create
end
```

This seems to do what you asked for me using Rails 4! This was based off of this answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929644/how-do-you-add-roles-rolify-using-cancan-and-devise/20931872#20931872)